# Django include url causes rendering error?

Tags: django, urlconf

I have a working django project. I wrote a small app - *pm* - and I tried to include its urls.py in the active project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... some urls here
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='vw_home'),
    # I added the following line:
    (r'^pm/', include('pm.urls')),
```

Once I access the main web page, I receive the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /
>   Caught error while rendering: syntax error

and the debug shows the problem in the following line:

`<a href="{% url vw_home %}">Home</a>`

If I remove the last url pattern (the `include()`), the page renders without any problem.
How can this be fixed?

EDIT:
Adding the urls.py of the *pm* app:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns("pm.views",
    url(r'^inbox/$', 'inbox', {'folder': 'inbox'}, name='vw_inbox'),
    url(r'^sent/$', 'inbox', {'folder': 'sent'}, name='vw_sent'),
    url(r'^message/(?<message_id>\w+)/$', 'read_message', name='vw_read_message'),
    url(r'^compose/(?P<profile_id>\w+)/$', 'compose_message', name='vw_compose_message'),
    url(r'^reply/(?P<message_id>\w+)/$', 'compose_message', name='vw_reply_message'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^message/(?<message_id>\w+)/$', 'read_message', name='vw_read_message'),
```

You missed **?P**

Comment: Thanks, I did miss the P. While this didn't solve the error, I found the source of the problem, which was a line in the pm/views.py file. I don't know why Django indicated that the problem was in the template of the main project. Thanks everyone

Comment: Anyway django couldn't compile regexp patterns with this misspell when you included patterns from `pm.urls`. Line in the `pm/views.py` was the second one.

Comment: Why does Django indicates in templates? Because Django loads modules lazily when you access them. If you imported `view` using `from pm.views import read_message` you would get error earlier.